# Unable to Post through AJAX from Partial View in MVC on Drop Down selection

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I am unable to post on DropDown Selection from my partial view , I dont see any problem with the code ... Where am i going wrong.
Following is the code for my **partial view** *_AccountInfo*:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.FTModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_AcctInfo";
    Dictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string,object>();
}

<script>

    //This code is not working ...
    var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "FundsTransfer")';
    $("#dropdownAcc").change(function () {
        var DropDownSelectedVal = $("#dropdownAcc").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { "Value": DropDownSelectedVal },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#placeHolder').html(response);
            }
    });
    });





    //This function works ... yet it does not show the details in Model.Selected_DebitObj 
    function MyFunc()
    {

        var DropDownSelectedVal = $("#dropdownAcc").val();
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FundsTransfer/Save",
                data: {
                    "Value": DropDownSelectedVal
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                complete: function() {
                    $('#nothing').hide();
                    $('#placeHolder').show();
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#placeHolder').html(response);
                    $('#placeHolder').show();
                    alert(document.getElementById('placeHolder'));
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Local error callback.");
                },
            });

    }
    </script>

<h2>Account Information</h2>




@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedAcctID, Model.Items_Debitables, "Please Select  ... ", new { id = "dropdownAcc",onchange="MyFunc()"})
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Selected_DebitObj.DebitableNumber))
{
    <div id="placeHolder" style="display:block">
   <p> Hey thereeee </p>
    @Model.Selected_DebitObj.Title
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.Title);
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.CurrencyMnemonic);
</div>
}
else
{
    <div id="nothing">
   <p>"Nothing Here Yet"</p>
    </div>
}
```

It alerts on success but div Place Holder is null and empty
I am trying to fire an action "save" in my controller on the Drop Down selection **while remaining on same page**, but i am unable to do so.

The method to which i m posting to is:

```
public PartialViewResult Save(string Value)
{
    FTModel Model = ApplicationWrapper.Model_ft;
    Model.Selected_DebitObj = Model.GetSlectedAcct(Value);
    ApplicationWrapper.Model_ft = Model;
    return PartialView("_AccountInfo", Model);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the tag [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*. You've already tagged it with the relevant ASP.NET implementation, so you don't need to (and shouldn't) add the pattern tag.

Comment: Show the method your posting to.

Comment: Is the controller method being hit? What if any error messages are you getting in the console? Note your returning a partial view, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Note also you don't need `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function () {` (the second is just shorthand for the first - [refer docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke
Please chk updated Code in my partail view ... yes its hitting the Controller action but it does not make changes on my view .. y is that so ..

I debugged ans stepped in. its going insde if{} brace but not displaying the content for:  @Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.Title);
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.CurrencyMnemonic);

Comment: But you have not done anything with the partial your returning. You need to update the DOM in the success callback. The `@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Selected_DebitObj.DebitableNumber))` block is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the client.

Comment: And go back to you original use of [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - i.e. `$('#dropdownAcc').change(function () {`  rather than polluting your markup with behavior.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Can you please show me what you are trying to say, i didnt get u.
I just wanted to save something in session thru controller action which i did, why will i use OnSuccess?

Comment: Your returning a partial view. Where in the main view do you want to display it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke
This is what i want to display: Model.Selected_DebitObj.DebitableNumber has been set by the method Save.  still its not being displayed

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Selected_DebitObj.DebitableNumber))
{
   <p> Hey thereeee </p>
    Model.Selected_DebitObj.Title
    Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.Title);
    Html.DisplayTextFor(X => X.Selected_DebitObj.CurrencyMnemonic);
}

Comment: You not understanding my question. You need to update the DOM with the partial your method returns. Where in the view do you want it to go? Immediately below the dropdown?

Comment: @StephenMuecke
yes immediately below DD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75100/discussion-between-sana-91-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

You method is returning a partial view, but you ajax call does not do anything with it (i.e. update the DOM). Add an element to your view as a placeholder for the partial

```
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```

and modify your script to update the DOM in the success callback

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "FundsTransfer")';
$("#dropdownAcc").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { value: $(this).val() },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#placeHolder').html(response);
    };
  });
});
```

or simply replace all the `ajax()` code with

```
$('#placeHolder').load(url, { value: $(this).val() });
```

Side note: From your comments I suspect your under the belief that calling the method will somehow run your `@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Selected_DebitObj.DebitableNumber)) {...}` block again. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Note sure what you partial view is, but it may be that you need to wrap that code block inside the placeholder div so it gets replaced by the partial?

Comment: This is not working for me either, its not displaying the data ... i have updated the code as u told me to ... still . it does hide the div in "else: braces but does not show the place Holder

i have updated the code in question.

Comment: Then either your `_AccountInfo` partial view does not render anything or you have not used my code correctly. Is the controller method being hit? What does `console.log(response)` return? Are the `id` attributes of the elements correct?

Comment: Now you have changed your question. You need to append new code you tried, not change existing code. Your new script is at the top of the page so it needs to be inside `document.ready` (or better, just place it immediately before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: Also you have included `<div id="placeHolder" style="display:block">` inside the if statement which is probably never hit so it wont be rendered so the scripts fail. Your whole `if/else` lock needs to be inside the `<div id="placeHolder">` tags (and you don't need `display:block`, but you do need to learn how to debug javascript)